# Generating random values in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am using the Real World Haskell book. The statement

```
ghci> import Test.QuickCheck
ghci> generate 10 (System.Random.mkStdGen 2) arbitrary :: [Bool]
```

results in

```
<interactive>:8:1: error:
* Couldn't match expected type `StdGen -> Gen a1 -> [Bool]'
              with actual type `IO a0'
* The function `generate' is applied to three arguments,
  but its type `Gen a0 -> IO a0' has only one
  In the expression: generate 10 (mkStdGen 2) arbitrary :: [Bool]
  In an equation for `it':
      it = generate 10 (mkStdGen 2) arbitrary :: [Bool]
```

If I am reading the error correctly it seems that "System.Random.mkStdGen 2" is now generating a monad? How do I get this statement to work?

Edit: Added import statement to clarify

Comment: What is `generate`? What is `arbitrary`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One key part of the error message you got is here:

```
* The function `generate' is applied to three arguments,
  but its type `Gen a0 -> IO a0' has only one
```

This is saying that `generate` should only take one element, but you've given it three.  Specifically, you've given it `10`, `System.Random.mkStdGen 2`, and `arbitrary`.  Just by looking at the types, it seems clear that your best bet to get a working program is to just drop the first two arguments to get:

```hs
generate arbitrary :: IO [Bool]
```

---

But, I'm guessing you had a reason for putting `10` and `mkStdGen 2` in, yes?  Perhaps you wanted to produce 10 `Bool`s (or 10 `[Bool]`?) and to use your own custom seed?  You can't just throw more arguments at a function to get it to do what you want, but if you follow the types, you'll get there.

First, there's using a custom seed.  To do this, we'll need to abandon `generate` and make our own `generateWithSeed`:

```hs
import Test.QuickCheck.Random (mkQCGen)

-- | Run a generator. The size passed to the generator is always 30;
-- if you want another size then you should explicitly use 'resize'.
generateWithSeed :: Int -> Gen a -> IO a
generateWithSeed seed (MkGen g) =
  do r <- mkQCGen seed
     return (g r 30)
```

Getting multiple results is actually easier -- we can use `replicateM`:

```hs
import Control.Monad (replicateM)

generateMultipleWithSeed :: Int -> Int -> Gen a -> IO [a]
generateMultipleWithSeed n seed g = generateWithSeed seed (replicateM n g)
```

Now you can run your original line (although with a slightly different type annotation):

```hs
generateMultipleWithSeed 10 2 (arbitrary :: Gen Bool)
```

Comment: This is great thanks. I'll give it a go. I guess the book is out of date on what the generate function takes or perhaps I am using the wrong generate.

Comment: I get 

error: Not in scope: data constructor `MkGen'
   
generateWithSeed seed (MkGen g)

Comment: Try adding `import Test.QuickCheck.Gen (Gen(MkGen))`